# Can I use vegalite v-5 in observable notebook using JSON syntax (not using vegalite API)?

Tags: vega-lite, observablehq

The `require("@observablehq/vega-lite")` doesn't allow us to use vegalite v-5. It uses older versions. I know `import {vl} from '@vega/vega-lite-api-v5'` allows us to use version-5 and write in more programmatic fashion. But, the syntax on the vegalite homepage and using API is different. So, isn't there any way to use vegalite v-5 in JSON syntax (like of examples on https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@observablehq/vega-lite was a helper to make vega-lite easier to embed in Observable notebooks, but it's not needed anymore since we now have an official Vega-embed module:

```js
// https://observablehq.com/@vega/hello-vega-embed
embed = require("vega-embed@6")
```

```js
embed({ vega or vega-lite spec… })
```

Note that Vega-embed accepts both Vega and Vega-lite specifications.